# Will a working GPU allways be displayed in the device manager ?

Tags: motherboard, gpu, pci-express

Supposing a working GPU is plugged into a working PCIe Slot, will it be automatically displayed inside of the device Manager of Windows, even if no Drivers are installed yet?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the hardware will be listed under 'Other Devices'. If it's automatically detected it will have the name listed, if not it will say 'Unknown Device'.

Comment: thx, so it will not be automatically put into the category "graphic Card" but "other devices" ?

Comment: Correct, it gets moved to the correct category after the driver is installed

Comment: so, if a GPU is plugged in into the Motherboard but does not Show up in the device Manager, then it is a hint, that there is something wrong with the GPU?

Comment: Yes if it doesn't show up at all there is a problem, but it could be a problem with the pcie slot. Try using your other slot for your gpu if your board has one.

Comment: i ve got only one PCIe Slot in which the GPU fits in. Is there no way of telling whether the GPU or PCIe Slot is broken?

Comment: The only practical way is testing another card in your PCIe slot or testing your gpu in another mobo.

Comment: I was worrying about this being my only Options, thank you for making it clear to me.

Comment: A device communicating with the computer can identify itself before a driver is installed and can therefore be in its correct section of the Device Manager even if a driver is not installed. If the OS does not recognize the device at all but the device is reporting correctly, it'll be listed under Unknown Devices or something similar.