# How do I manually install a driver for the GPU msi R9 290x gaming 4GB?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gpu, amd-radeon

I bought a second-hand pc,
it works, but the GPU does not Show up inside the device Manager.

I downloaded the AMD catalyst Software, but it failed repeatedly during installation.

I want to try to install the Driver manually, but I even do not know how to search for it, since I searched for hours without success.

Please, help me, give me advice how to install the Driver manually for the R9 290x gaming 4GB, you are my last hope.

Comment: You can force the installation of the driver but that won't make the device functional if it's not showing up in device manager.

Answer (score 1):

So I saw [your other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1193702/will-a-working-gpu-allways-be-displayed-in-the-device-manager) and I'm not sure installing the driver will help if the GPU isn't being recognized. If you really wanted to, you may be able to extract the contents of the driver with 7-zip and find the setup files for just the driver. It MAY bypass a check for the GPU being present. Unfortunately, doing a more manual install than that would take a large amount of effort on your part as you'd have to make sure that every script that the setup needs to run, gets run. So 7-zip is probably the easiest way to go.

To do this, you just need to install the program from [7-zip.org](http://7-zip.org/) and then once you have it setup, you can right click the setup executable you get from AMD, go to 7z then "extract to here". (You may want to move the EXE into its own folder before doing so.)

Though keep in mind the bigger problem is your computer not detecting your GPU. Windows still has to see your GPU before it can assign drivers to it.

Comment: thank you for making clear to me, that the main Problem is the the Computer not detecting the GPU, this assured me, since I wanted to try to install it manually out of ignorance and despair.

Comment: Honestly. If the GPU is new. Id take it back and get it swapped out. If not I'll update my answer shortly.